# How to Add a Unique Identifier to a Dataframe Utilizing the "between" Function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with *MLB Statcast data* in *RStudio* and am trying to determine which pitchers utilizes each portion of the strike zone the most.

*Statcast* gives the coordinates of where the ball crossed the pate as `plate_x` (the left/right distance, in feet, of the pitch from the middle of the plate as it crossed home plate), and `plate_z` (the height of the pitch in feet as it crossed the front of home plate).

Example `dataframe`:

```
pitcher_name <- c('AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ 
Griffin','AJ Griffin','Adam Conley','Adam Conley','Adam Conley','Adam Conley')

plate_x <- c(0.88, -0.74, 0.54, 0.51, 0.54, 0.49, -0.70, -0.67, 0.78, 0.58)

plate_z <- c(1.63, 1.81, 2.03, 2.60, 1.83, 1.58, 2.82, 2.13, 1.10, 1.72)

strike_zone_analysis <- data.frame(pitcher_name, plate_x, plate_z)
```

I'm looking to isolate lower strikes, which I can do using the between function built into `dplyr`:

```
low_zone <- strike_zone_analysis %>% filter(between(plate_x, -1.01, 1.01), 
                                            between(plate_z, 1.49, 2.17))
```

What I want to do next is assign a unique identifier (new column that states low strike vs. non-low strike) using mutate in dplyr that fits the data points specific to the between function above. My ultimate goal is to calculate the portion of low strikes pitches each pitcher has thrown overall using code similar to:

```
P <- pitch_analysis.data %>% 
     group_by(pitcher_name) %>%     
     summarise(r=sum(str_detect(description,"swinging"))/n())
```

Not sure exactly how to combine the mutate and between functions of `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
strike_zone_analysis %>%
  mutate(low_zone = between(plate_x, -1.01, 1.01) & between(plate_z, 1.49, 2.17)) %>%
  group_by(pitcher_name) %>%
  summarize(low_percent = sum(low_zone)/n())
```

You can combine the two criteria in mutate and then group and sum the the logicals which convert to binary.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing what you are looking for is

```
strike_zone_analysis %>% 
  group_by(pitcher_name) %>%
  summarize(
    low_strike_per = mean( (plate_x > -1.01 & plate_x < 1.01) & (plate_z > 1.49 & plate_z < 2.17))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an `ifelse` statement with `mutate`. If the pitch is between the low zone parameters a 1 will be placed in the new "low_zone" column, else a 0 will be entered. Then you can `group_by` pitcher and `summarise` as below.

```
strike_zone_analysis %>%
  mutate(low_zone = ifelse(between(plate_x, -1.01, 1.01) & 
                             between(plate_z, 1.49, 2.17), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(pitcher_name) %>%
  summarise(n_of_pitches = n(),
            prop_low_zone = sum(low_zone)/n_of_pitches)


# A tibble: 2 x 3
  pitcher_name n_of_pitches prop_low_zone
        <fctr>        <int>         <dbl>
1  Adam Conley            4     0.5000000
2   AJ Griffin            6     0.8333333
```